# Find a Sylow $p$-subgroup satisfying the given condition

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $H$ and $N$ be two subgroups contained in $G$ such that $N$ is normal. I showed that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, $P\cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. I need to show the following next: if $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, there exist a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that $P\cap H=S$.

I could not figure out how I should proceed?

Can I use any consequence of the fact that I proved as I mentioned above? Or do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a natural exercise. I am fairly sure that we have covered it. The claim follows, for example, from the fact that every $p$-subgroup is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup. A hint for one approach: Consider the conjugation action of $S$ on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. What kind of orbits can there be? Are there somehow special orbits?

Comment: This has been subject of many answers here on Math Stack Exchange. I do not have the URLs now, but keep looking. Otherwise we will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S \in Syl_p(H)$, then, since $S$ is a $p$-group, there must be a $P \in Syl_p(G)$, such that $S \subseteq P$. Hence $S \subseteq H \cap P$. On the other hand, $P \cap H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$, hence $P \cap H \subseteq S^h$, for some $h \in H$. It follows that $|P \cap H| \leq |S^h|=|S|$. But we already saw that $S \subseteq P \cap H$, so we must have $S=P \cap H$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome!